# 2 different font sizes for text inside basic Rect, jointjs

Tags: jointjs

I have a basic Rect shape like this:

```
  var rectShape = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
  position: { x: 60, y: 10 },
  size: { width: 160, height: 35 },
  attrs: {
    rect: {
        fill: '#F5F5F5'
    },
    text: {
        fill: '#FC8A26',
        'font-size': 12,
        'font-weight': 'bold',
        'font-variant': 'small-caps'
    }
  }
 });
```

I use `clone()` to create more rectangles like that one:

```
var rect1 = rectShape.clone().translate(520, 10).attr('text/text','rect1');
```

I want to have 2 different words inside the rect, one at the size 12 and the other at  the size 8. Any idea on how I can do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a custom shape with new SVG markup containing a text element that contains a `<tspan>` for each word that you want. You could adapt the markup from the standard Rect element. Give each element a different class name, for example replace the `<text/>` element in the Rect markup with  `<text><tspan class="word1"/><tspan class="word2"/></text>`. The shape definition would look like this:

```
joint.shapes.my.twoTextRect = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend({

    markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect/></g><text><tspan class="word1"></tspan> <tspan class="word2"></tspan></text></g>',

    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({

        type: 'my.twoTextRect',
        attrs: {
            rect: { fill: 'white', stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 1, 'follow-scale': true, width: 160, height: 35 },
            text: { ref: 'rect' },
            '.word1': { 'font-size': 12 },
            '.word2': { 'font-size': 8 }

        },
        size: { width: 160, height: 35 }
    }, joint.shapes.basic.Generic.prototype.defaults)
});
```

Then to create your shape instance:

```
  var rectShape = new joint.shapes.my.twoTextRect();
```

To set the text of the `<tspan>` SVG elements you can use

```
rectShape.attr('.word1/text', 'word 1');
rectShape.attr('.word2/text', 'word 2');
```

This results in an element that looks like this:

[image: rectangle with two words of different sizes]

You can clone the element like this:

```
var clone = rectShape.clone().translate(520, 10).attr({'.word1': {text: 'clone1'}, '.word2': {text: 'clone2' }});
```

And this makes a new element:

[image: cloned rectangle]

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! i changed Rect markup as you said, also i added '.word1' and '.word2', but i don`t know how to tell clone() about this 2 different words. Any idea?

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, but I guess .attr('.word1/text/text', 'rect1') or something similar

Comment: I tried every combination of arguments in attr and still doesn't work. It doesn't show any text. 
Is there something else i should try? Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I added some instructions on how to set the text of the `<tspan>` elements. Hope its not too late.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin Could you please answer a joint js question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794098/error-while-fetching-json-from-database