# Text overlapping in jointjs shape with multiple tspan tags

Tags: svg, jointjs

I have a custom jointjs Rect shape which displays text with 2 different font sizes:

```
twoTextRect= joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend({
markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect/></g><text><tspan class="word1"></tspan><tspan class="word2"></tspan></text></g>',
defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    type: 'twoTextRect',
    attrs: {
        rect: { fill: 'white', stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 1, 'follow-scale': true, width: 160, height: 160},
        text: { ref: 'rect', 'font-size':20},
        '.word1': { 'fill':'red'},
        '.word2': { 'fill':'blue'}
    },
    size: { width: 160, height: 35 }
}, joint.shapes.basic.Generic.prototype.defaults)});
```

Then I create my shape instance and set the text for word1 and word2:

```
var rect3 = new twoTextRect();
rect3.attr('.word1/text' , 'aaa');
rect3.attr('.word2/text', 'bbbbbb');
```

I created it according to this answer: [2 different font sizes for text inside basic Rect, jointjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556728/2-different-font-sizes-for-text-inside-basic-rect-jointjs)

The problem is that the text I set in word1 and word2 overlaps instead of being displayed in a raw, word1 and word2 both start at the begining of the rect instead of appearing one after the other... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to position the texts using below or similar options so that they don't overlap

```
'.word1': { 'fill':'red', ref-x:0.5, ref-y:1},
'.word2': { 'fill':'blue', , ref-x:0.5, ref-y:1}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it wont work for me since I want to create this shape dynamically, each time with different text...